# Prestashop Add to cart button does not work in ie (internet explore)

Tags: prestashop

Prestashop ADD TO CART button does not work in ie(internet explore) but other browser works properly. When I click the add to cart button it does not work properly. Prestashop's online demo also get same problem. Can I get any suggestion please.

Comment: Update your Internet Explorer? Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using internet explorer 11 ......